# Responsive layout with two divs inside another div

Tags: css

I have this HTML structure.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="BandC">
        <div class="B"></div>
        <div class="C"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have the following layout if the screen width is more than or equal to, say 800px...

[image]

... but I want this when the width is less than 800px.

[image]

The challenge for me here is that B and C are in the same div. I put B and C in the same div so that if content overflows vertically, a scroll bar will appear next to B and C.

Here is what I have so far ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8LmL/)). I used `display:flexbox` to move .BandC to the right, but B stays on top of C because they are in the same div.

How can I achieve this layout while allowing B and C to be in the same div? Or does this require change in my HTML?

Comment: Would Bootstrap be an option? You could solve this problem in less than 1 minute.

Comment: In the first example A has a fixed height and width? And what happens to the height of B if C  contains more text?

Comment: @Chevi No Bootstrap/Foundation. :( But I don't think I can do this with either one of them. The problem is that B and C are in the same container. Please show me an example, then I can just mimic how it is done.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, The height of A could be specified in px or in %.

Comment: try 960 grid system and use adapt.js with that.[adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/)

Comment: @AtalShrivastava, It seems similar to the CSS grid layout used in Bootstrap and other front-end frameworks, and I don't think they can provide what I am looking for because I'm trying to go against the grid flow. (But I am ready to be proven wrong.) I believe `display:flex` is the best bet, but I was not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used `position:absolute` to put C out of the container div.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8LmL/2/)